# Multisite Wordpress, SSL and htaccess to use the subfolder as a root

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, ssl, multisite

I have an SSL sertificate, so http -> https is a must (as a precaution). I intend to have multiple subdomains, i.e. subdomain1.example.com, subdomain2.example.com, currently there is one subdomain that works without any issues. I'm using a multisite Wordpress setup, that was installed (purposely) in one subfolder. The multisite setup is for other languages. The current server folder layout is as follows:

- public_html

  - backstage
  - - subdomain1 (folder for the subdomain)
  - frontstage
  - - wp-admin
  - - wp-content
  - - wp-includes
  - - (the rest of the WP files)
  - index.php (a test file, that shouldn't load if the redirection is set up properly)

Currently, the www.example.com/frontstage/ opens the main WP site, this is fine. I can access its wp-admin without issues. www.example.com/frontstage/en/ shows a 404 page, this is not fine. www.example.com/frontstage/en/wp-admin/ opens the dashboard fine for the other site.

I want to retain the stripping out of index.php from any links (to keep the links clean).

There are two "simple" things to configure properly:

1. I want to retain the server folder structure as it is, but having the "frontstage" folder skipped, so that when you visit www.example.com, the main WP site loads (and in the case someone would load www.example.com/frontstage/ it would redirect to www.example.com). Naturally, the "shift" needs to allow for the www.example.com/en/ to open the secondary website (any any other language sites that may follow). Ideally without rewriting all the links within the WP sites.
2. Currently the /en/ site doesn't load its root. The demo posts and pages load fine.

My current .htaccess on the root level looks like this:

```bsh
# disable index.php from urls

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    # redirect index.php requests
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

# force https and www

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

# move wordpress one level up

# allow subdomain

RewriteRule ^backstage\/subdomain1\/?(.*)$ "https\:\/\/subdomain1\.example\.com\/$1" [R=301,L]
```

Any help with this is highly appreciated (I'm still learning the htaccess bits and tricks and this one is truly beyond me). What am I missing in the above code to get it right?

Answer (score 0):

When I have WP installed within a subfolder, I just goto Settings => General and change the Website URL by removing the subfolder.

Afterwards I move the file index.php one folder level up and in your case, would change it to:

```
 require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/frontstage/wp-blog-header.php' );
```

Does this solve your problem?

Find a detailed description how to move WP to a subdirectory on this site - You can find a detailed description about putting Wordpress in a subdirectory on the following website  https://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory

Regarding a redirection from http to https - this is possible within the .htaccess. Much better, in my opinion, would be an alias on the apache (this usually should be done by your hoster).

The difference:

The htaccess redirect goes back to the user and then again to the server, which costs some time. The alias is - as far as I know - redirected on the server.

if you want to force https, you can do it with the following entry.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Tried with the procedure you describe, I get a blank start page with the error "Can't establish a database connection" - something along those lines, written in a large black font (generated by WP, not by the server).

Regarding the https, I left that in the htaccess just out of precaution, in case the SSL validity ends (and I guess I'll be moving to another server pretty soon, with not being able to immediately transfer the SSL).

Comment: Isn't the current statement just checking if it is not https that it will forward to the same link with https, but if it is https (as probably properly configured by the host, I get https links even without that piece of code in the htaccess) it just skips any action on that matter?

Comment: Did you reset the htaccess to the original one?

Comment: If you mean the WPs htaccess, it was untouched from the start, I only made changes in the root's htaccess (my custom htaccess, everything in the folders works fine even without it)

Comment: I would remove any htaccess.

Comment: I added above the lines to force a https redirection.

Comment: I've cleared the root htaccess, copied the /frontend/index.php to the root, and modified its require path ... what happens is that FF & Opera show the message "Error establishing a database connection", while IE shows the 500 browser error. In the current setup, www.example.com/wp-admin/ is returning a 404 error on all browsers. Changing the WP database siteurl and/or home paths doesn't help.

At the same time, www.example.com/frontend/ displays the page as it should. /frontend/en/ doesn't show the other site, but /frontend/en/wp-admin/ loads the login page.

Comment: One error left to solve, I can't get the /en/ (index page of the secondary site) to load, but its /en/wp-admin works without issues ... still need to confirm all of that, but so far so good

Comment: Before I answer my own question (still need to resolve the /en/ second site index page) ... the solution became fairly simple once I've added these two lines in the .htaccess files:

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !front/
RewriteRule (.*) /front/$1 [L]

Of course, changes to the database folders (removing the frontend folder from definition links of the blog and sites) were also required, but that won't help if the .htaccess isn't configured properly